# How to solve this particular system of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & -3\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}

I reduced the original linear system to reduced row-echelon form and now I need to solve it. I tried by it doesn't seem to work.
Would very much appreciate your assistance.

Edit: this is an augmented matrix. So basically I am trying to solve the following system:

$$x_{1}-x_{4}=2\\
x_{2}+2x_{4}=-3\\
x_{3}-x_{4}=2\\$$

Comment: Is this an augmented matrix or coefficient matrix?

Comment: Augmented matrix. The last column to the right does not represent coefficients.

Comment: You have the equations $x_1-x_4=2$, $x_2+2x_4=-3$ and $x_3-x_4=2$

Thus, the solution to the system becomes:

$$x_1=2+x_4$$  
$$x_2 = -3 -2x_4$$  
$$x_3 = 2+x_4$$  
$$x_4=x_4$$

Comment: I didn't understand why there was no solution to $x_{4}$. So $x_{4}$ is basically a parameter?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, since $x_4$ can take any value. In particular, you are asked to solve a system of 4 variables given only 3 equations, which will not result in an unique solution.

Comment: @user2357 Yes, that's correct. It doesn't matter what it is.Try to replace the above formulas in the initial system with $x_4=x_4$ and you'll see it doesn't matter what $x_4$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your help. By the way, is there a quicker way to solve systems of linear equations? Or do I have to always reduce the matrix to row-echelon?

Comment: You can try the well known substitution method. Sometimes it's easier, sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found $\begin{cases} x_1-x_4&=2\\
x_2+2x_4&=-3\\
x_3-x_4&=2\end{cases}$, which is equivalent to $\begin{cases} x_1&=x_3\\
x_1&=2+x_4\\
x_2&=-3-2x_4\end{cases}$.

So the set of solutions is $\{(2+x_4, -3-2x_4, 2+x_4, x_4)\colon x_4\in \mathbb F\}.$

Answer (score 0):

From $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & -3\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$ you only have to paint, no to calculate, to get the solution: expand the matrix in this

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & -3\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 2\\
0&0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$
way and convince yourself that the solution set is
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}2\\ -3\\ 2 \\ 0\\ -1\end{bmatrix}
+t\begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 2\\ -1\\ -1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}\mid t\in R\right\}.$$